# unable to use pymongo in ubuntu 20

Tags: python, mongodb, ubuntu, pymongo

I try to insert some data in mongoDB using Python3, so I install the pymongo library using this command `pip install pymongo`and I follow every step from this [link](https://api.mongodb.com/python/3.0.3/installation.html), finally I write this script below:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('localhost')
print (client)
db = client.clients
db.clients.count()
clients = db.clients
clients.find()
```

But when I execute the script, the process finish and show me this error:

[image]

However when I try to use python3 directly from the terminal and I write `import pymongo`, nothing happened as shown the screenshot below:

[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 20 and Python 3.8, and the script saved in my desktop with the name `example4_DB.py`also I create the script using the terminal by tapping this command: `nano example4_DB.py` and this command to execute the script: `sudo python3 example4_DB.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you shouldn't run python using `sudo`; as it will not necessarily pick up the installed modules created using `pip` running under your own user account.

Try just running:

```
python3 example4_DB.py
```

Comment: It's work thanks! please how can I fix this issue if I want for example to run the script using `sudo` ?

Answer (score 1):

Install `pymongo` under current user:

```
pip3 install --user pymongo
```

And run the Python file under current user, too:

```
python3 example4_DB.py
```